# Superposition theorem

Tags: dc, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm trying to apply the superposition theorem.

[image]

I'm confused how the value of \$I_2\$ is calculated, from where does the value of 1 come?

Answer (score 5):

> from where the value of 1 comes?

It's the 1 ohm resistance of r2.  As other answers point out, this step is basic [current division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider).  Using *conductances*, \$G = \frac{1}{R}\$, current division has the form of [voltage division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) (in fact, current division is the *[dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28electrical_circuits%29#Voltage_division_.E2.80.94_current_division)* of voltage division).

Voltage division for two series connected resistors:

\$V_{R_1} = V_S \dfrac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}\$

Current division for two parallel connected resistors:

\$I_{R_1} = I_S \dfrac{G_1}{G_1 + G_2} \$

Note that these equations are *duals*.  If you know one of these, you get the other by [duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28electrical_circuits%29).

Applying the 2nd equation to your problem:

\$I_2 = I_1 \dfrac{G}{G + g_2} = I_1 \dfrac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{1}} = I_1 \dfrac{1}{1 + 4}\$

Answer (score 2):

The textbook example isn't using the superposition theorem at all. It is using the current divider rule to determine \$I_2\$. \$I_1\$ is determined from the single circuit formed by reducing the parallel resistors to an equivalent resistance. Then current division is applied. \$I_1\$ splits into two currents \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$ through the 4Ω resistor and the 1Ω resistor. The split must be 4:1 according to the current divider rule: 1/5th of the current goes through the bigger resistor and 4/5ths go through the smaller resistor.  The mysterious 1 boxed in red comes from the 1Ω: \$\frac{1\Omega}{4\Omega + 1\Omega}\$.

Comment: this example was given under superposition theorem

Answer (score 1):

Use U<sub>n</sub> as a helper for the node voltage.

\$I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \tag{1}\$

\$I_2 = \dfrac{U_n}{R} \tag{2}\$

\$I_3 = \dfrac{U_n}{r_2} \tag{3}\$

\$I_1 = \dfrac{U_n}{R} + \dfrac{U_n}{r_2}\tag{4}\$

\$I_1 = \dfrac{U_n\cdot r_2}{R \cdot r_2} + \dfrac{U_n \cdot R}{r_2 \cdot R} = \dfrac{U_n \cdot r_2+ U_n \cdot R}{R \cdot r_2} \tag{5}\$

\$I_1 = \dfrac{U_n}{R}\cdot \dfrac{R+r_2}{r_2} = I_2 \cdot \dfrac{R + r_2}{r_2}\tag{6}\$

\$I_2 = \boxed{\dfrac{r_2}{R+r_2} \cdot I_1} = \dfrac{\boxed{1}}{4+1} \cdot I_1\tag{7}\$

Which is the current divider as mentioned by [@Kaz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/71029/8627)

Comment: Hmm little confused,this might be stupid,How can you say that I2=Un/R AND I3=Un/r2,Is this calculated by taking into account only the resistances in the particular branch and does Un stands for the voltage drop im not familier with the helper thing.

Comment: I took Un as the potential difference between the top node and the bottom node in the circuit. It is the voltage across R and r2, which is the same voltage. It is the node where I1 goes in and I2, I3 flows out. I am not really interested in the node voltage, but it renders the formulas nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy used in the Superposition Theorem is to eliminate all but one source of power within a network at a time, using series/parallel analysis to determine voltage drops (and/or currents) within the modified network for each power source separately. Then, once voltage drops and/or currents have been determined for each power source working separately, the values are all “superimposed” on top of each other (added algebraically) to find the actual voltage drops/currents with all sources active.

Have a look at http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_10/7.html

You might also want to look at Thevenin and Norton equivalant circuits (black box approach).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thévenin's_theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton's_theorem

I remember the great aha moment came when we were introduced to **mesh current analysis** when the circuit could be written down in matrix form by simple inspection.
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_10/3.html

They all come back to ohm's and kirchoffs laws.